# AngularJS ng-click on table row but not on a certain td

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm facing an issue when there is an event data-ng-click on table row,
but i want that a certain td won't do the event in the row.

is it possible to do it?

if so, how?

example html:

```
      <table>
          <tr data-ng-click="do_some_action()">
              <td>
                  cell 1 is clickable
              </td>
              <td>
                  cell 2 is clickable
              </td>
              <td class="not-clickable-cell">
                  cell 3 is not! clickable
              </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can stop event propagation like this:

```
<td class="not-clickable-cell" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
    cell 3 is not! clickable
</td>
```

so that when you click this cell event will not bubble up to the `tr` event handler.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/jvh5NKaDsvpPKuSJhzFx?p=preview

Comment: I had buttons inside my table that had clickable rows. I wanted clicking in that column around the button to still perform an action, so I did this:

`<td><button ng-click="doThing();$event.stopPropagation()"></td>`

Comment: Try this @JackCole  `<td ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"><button ng-click="doThing();"></td>`

Comment: The problem with that is the button doesn't fill the cell 100%, so there is area inside the cell that neither would trigger the button's function nor the row's function, resulting in a frustrating user experience in the event they click on that area. The solution I used works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could write something in the do_some_action function that explicitly makes it ignore the class "not-clickable-call". It would be a easier to say with a jsfiddle or example of what that function is.

Answer (score 0):

simply add ng-click where you want click event

```
<table>
      <tr >
          <td data-ng-click="do_some_action()">
              cell 1 is clickable
          </td>
          <td>
              cell 2 is clickable
          </td>
          <td class="not-clickable-cell">
              cell 3 is not! clickable
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dajukidi/1/)

Comment: not useful. if I have 50 td cells and only 5 shouldn't propagate, do you suggest I make 45 <td data-ng-click="do_some_action()">  cells? Not a feasible solution.